# $L_2$ Norm equivalence of a polynomial function on two neighbouring elements

Tags: integration, inequality, polynomials, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

Let $P_p$ be a set of polynomial functions of degree less than or equal to p. Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be two neighbouring elements sharing a common face.

There is a theory saying that the following holds: for $v\in P_p$

$$ \|v\|_{L^2(T_1)}\leq C\|v\|_{L^2(T_2)}$$

where C is a constant that depends on polynomial degree and mesh regularity.

How can we prove this? I want to see the explicit dependance of C on p.

If possible, can you help me to prove the above inequality? 
I will be equally happy if you give me a reference for a proof.

Thank you in advance!

Balemlay